# Regex unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

When I add this regex into validation engine I get a javascript error: "unexpected token", it seems that the regex is wrong because it is underline with red, why?

```
"time1":{    
   "regex": ^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$,
   "alertText": "* Invalid Time"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace

```
   "regex": ^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$,
```

with

```
   "regex": /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/,
```

See [the syntax of regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 3):

It should be either string (if you use `new RegExp()` with it):

```
"regex": "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"
```

or regex literal:

```
"regex": /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```